# Are there any fully programmable DSP chips with built in ADC & DAC?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

Using Analog Devices as an example. They have SigmaDSP chips with on board ADCs and DACs, but they are not very programmable. They are rely on a high level IDE with very standard audio processing blocks. Alternatively they have SHARC chips which are fully programmable, but no on board ADCs, DACs.

I want to make a custom embedded single channel audio autocorrelation algorithm, with as few external components as possible.

Comment: Hm, are you *sure* you're saving *anything* by not using an external Codec? You'd generally want these, anyway, since they usually come with things like adjustable amplifiers, filters,  more output power and so on.

Comment: What do you mean by 'programmable'? every micro\dsp is programmable.

Comment: @laptop2d I mean programmable by C++ like a SHARC DSP, not by being forced to use pre-defined blocks in a visual IDE, like with SigmaDSP.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the application is not to fussy about sampling resolution, I can work with the built in Codec. I want to make the PCB design as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHARC DSP's aren't true DSP's, they probably don't have a built in microcontroller.

> There is not a C compiler for SigmaDSP, and we do not support custom assembly coding in SigmaStudio. The built-in library includes many different signal processing blocks. Low-level blocks, such as multipliers and delays, can be wired together in SigmaStudio to create a custom algorithm if the included libraries do not have the functions you want. If there are processing blocks that you'd like to see included in future versions of the tool, feel free to let us know what you're looking for in the EngineerZone forum.

It sounds to me like this is not a microcontroller with compiled code, but more of a signal chain where they are setting muxes and registers to control the path of the signal, more like an FPGA.

From my experience your only going to find what you want in :
1) A mixed signal FPGA (actel makes some, probably not with the flavors of ADC's you want)
2) Another manufacturer like TI that does DSP and analog.

Most people don't do 24-bit signaling in a microcontroller, if people need that they buy a separate ADC

Comment: So I may be able to do it in Sigma Studio by working with their low level blocks, but it is difficult to know how flexible it really is. I might have a play around with it, it looks fairly easy to use. Do mean SigmaDSP is not true DSP? SHARC very different from SigmaDSP.

Answer (score 0):

Atmel xmega has ADCs and DACs, can be programmed in C/C++, and can even run at 32 MHz on the internal oscillator.  However, I'm not sure if it is powerful enough for your application (it's not really a 'DSP' chip).

Comment: Ok I will look into it, the algorithm is doing autocorrelation over 25ms in real time. So it will need to do about 1000 multiplies per second as the main bulk of the processing.

Comment: "autocorrelation over 25ms" <--- sampling rate?

Comment: Ah, I see It would need a lot more multiplies. Would the number of multiplies per block be the square of the number samples per block? I was thinking of 44kHz sample rate.